# finding the depth of specific node in binary search tree in java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, depth

If I got a method of int depth(T data), I was asked to find the depth of its corresponding depth in a binary search tree.
I tried this code as below, but it does not work:

```
public int depth(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new Exception();
    } else {
        if (!contains(data)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return depth(root, data);
        }
    }
}

private int depth(BSTNode<T> processingNode, T data) {
    if (processingNode.getData().compareTo(data) < 0) {
        return 1 + depth(processingNode.getRight(), data);
    } else if (processingNode.getData().compareTo(data) > 0) {
        return 1 + depth(processingNode.getLeft(), data);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

It seems like recursion does not work as the return value is always 1.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code - have you tried using a debugger to trace execution of the program?

Comment: maybe you're only ever finding the root node